# Best way to lookup a list of character strings against dictionary to output English words

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a list of about 20,000 strictly alpha/text character strings outputted as a CSV file to Excel, but it's quite a mess.
What I want to do is query a separate, reference file of English dictionary words so that I can essentially create a lookup and return the dictionary word, minus a load of the text noise that is either prepended or appended to the string. Example below.

```
xyzbuildingcontractor = Building Contractor 
upholsteryabcdef = Upholstery 
lmnoengineer = Engineer
```

As a relative n00b programmer I just want to gauge opinion as to the best way to do this and whether Excel is the best platform to use.

Any guidance would be very gratefully recieved, thanks in advance.

Jim

Comment: Question is unclear - what *exactly* does "minus a load of the text noise that is either prepended or appended to the string" mean in practice?

Comment: If the "text noise" is able to be described well enough to strip it out, I would suggest doing that instead. If you really want to "return the dictionary word..." or word*s*, plural, as in your example, you would need to parse through each string character by character and use a Trie data structure to check for complete words to pull out.  Unfortunately, there is no built-in Trie class in VBA, so you'd have to roll your own...

Comment: @TimWilliams
Thanks for the response and apologies if this was unclear. I merely meant that I wanted to be able to strip out the random characters, either in front of or at the end of the part of the string that is recognised as an English dictionary word or phrase, as per the lookup. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Blackhawk
Thanks for your response. I am vaguely aware of Trie structures but not sure that is entirely necessary here? What I'm trying to do is say "Does *Any dictionary word/phrase* exist within character string".
What I'm struggling with is how to do this without it taking an absolute age to complete! 
20000 character strings multiplied by a lookup of 170,000 English dictionary entries...

Comment: The way a trie works is that you navigate down a tree of words letter by letter, and if you make it down to a leaf, you have a complete word. If at any point the next letter isn't one of the children of the current node in the tree, you know you're looking at a word that doesn't exist in the Trie and you can stop tracking it. In your case, you'd have to start navigating the Trie starting over for each new letter, but AS SOON as you reach the point where it can't be a word, you can stop tracking it.  This is actually exactly what Tries are designed to do.  The alternative would be...

Comment: ... a huge number of substring lookups in a hash table or something similar, but since you don't know the length of the words necessarily, you'd have to check for every possible substring >= the length of the smallest word and <= the longest word, which even for small character strings would be prohibitively many.  The trouble with a Trie is that none exists by default in VBA.  I've been interested in making one for a while, but I don't have the time at the moment :'(  You can see examples on wikipedia, but the Trie is also often used for autocomplete or spell checking.

Comment: It's not an easy (or quick) task to perform.  for example, many words contain other words: "contract" for example also appears in "xyzcontractor", so you have to avoid lopping off both the "xyz" *and* the "or".  Sorting your lookup dictionary in order of descending length might help with that. You might be able to improve performance by building a dictionary of "original" vs "fixed" word pairs as you go though: that way you can quickly repeat word switches without having to run through the lookup again each time you encounter the same input.

Comment: I should correct myself: I had said "if you make it down to a leaf, you have completed a word". This is not strictly the case. Suppose you had the words "homework" and "home" stored in a Trie. "e" wouldn't be a leaf node in this case, but it would mark the end of a word. This is indicated by either storing a value in that node (if the Trie is an associative array) or otherwise flagging it.

Comment: I'm taking a stab at this - should there be a preference for longest match or will that not be an issue? To take my earlier example, if the dictionary contains both "home" and "homework", and the string is "thedogatemyhomework", should the match be greedy ("home") or lazy ("homework")?

Comment: Thanks again all, really great responses! Better than I'd hopes for.

@Blackhawk I guess in this example, being that all those words appear in the dictionary the output would be all five words "The", "Dog", "Ate", "My", "Homework" due to the fact that there is nothing nonsensical in this string to exclude. I guess what would be also be beneficial then would be some way of grouping the outputs by number of words contained.

Comment: In browsing for further answers I actually came across a product called ZipZing which someone has created seemingly for the purpose of organising lists of domain names in exactly the way I'm trying to do here. Only at $800 it's a little too expensive for me!

Comment: @jimiclapton I meant, what if the string is something like "123h123i1n2homework14j2i43n4".  The only word is "homework", but technically it could also be treated as having two separate words, "home" and "work". The choice is either to take the shortest complete word or the longest complete word. Which makes more sense in your case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this is a **very rough draft** which you might have to tweak, but the general idea is this:

1. A Trie is used to build a dictionary of words
2. A `clsTrieIterator` class allows tracking multiple words at a time within the Trie
3. The string to be tested is parsed one character at a time, each one starting a new `clsTrieIterator`
4. All the existing active `clsTrieIterators` consume each next character, and if the resulting combination of characters is not possible given the dictionary, it stops being tracked

Here is a short example of the use:

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim wf As clsWordFinder
    Set wf = New clsWordFinder
    
    wf.Add "Building"
    wf.Add "Contractor"
    wf.Add "Upholstery"
    wf.Add "Engineer"
        
    Debug.Print wf.getWordsFromString("xyzbuildingcontractor")
    Debug.Print wf.getWordsFromString("upholsteryabcdef")
    Debug.Print wf.getWordsFromString("lmnoengineer")
End Sub
```

Which outputs the following to the immediate window in VBA:

> Building Contractor
>
> Upholstery
>
> Engineer

...and below are the classes.

`clsTrieNode` is each individual node of the tree. It represents a single letter and it may have up to 26 children, assuming they form valid words in the dictionary. If the combination of characters, node by node down the tree from the root to this point forms a word, the Trie will set "isWord".

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public KeyChar As String
Public isWord As Boolean

Private m_Children(0 To 25) As clsTrieNode

Public Property Get Child(strChar As String) As clsTrieNode
    'better be ONE char
    Set Child = m_Children(charToIndex(strChar))
End Property

Public Property Set Child(strChar As String, oNode As clsTrieNode)
    Set m_Children(charToIndex(strChar)) = oNode
End Property

Private Function charToIndex(strChar As String) As Long
    charToIndex = Asc(strChar) - 97 'asc("a")
End Function
```

`clsTrie` is the public facing interface to interact with the tree of nodes that forms the trie. It contains an `Add` method to put words into the dictionary and an `isWord` method which allows testing a string against the trie dictionary to see if it is a valid word. `Remove` is a method that is nice to have, but probably not necessary for your problem, so I haven't implemented it.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private m_Head As clsTrieNode

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_Head = New clsTrieNode
End Sub

Public Sub Add(strKey As String)
    Dim currNode As clsTrieNode
    Dim tempNode As clsTrieNode
    Set currNode = m_Head
    
    Dim strLCaseKey As String
    strLCaseKey = LCase(strKey)
    
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 1 To Len(strLCaseKey)
        If Not currNode.Child(Mid(strLCaseKey, i, 1)) Is Nothing Then
            Set currNode = currNode.Child(Mid(strLCaseKey, i, 1))
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    
    For i = i To Len(strLCaseKey)
        Set tempNode = New clsTrieNode
        tempNode.KeyChar = Mid(strLCaseKey, i, 1)
        Set currNode.Child(Mid(strLCaseKey, i, 1)) = tempNode
        Set currNode = tempNode
    Next
    currNode.isWord = True
End Sub

Public Sub Remove(strKey As String)
    'Might be nice to have
End Sub

Public Function isWord(strKey As String)
    Dim currNode As clsTrieNode
    Set currNode = m_Head
    
    Dim strLCaseKey As String
    strLCaseKey = LCase(strKey)
    
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 1 To Len(strLCaseKey)
        If Not currNode.Child(Mid(strLCaseKey, i, 1)) Is Nothing Then
            Set currNode = currNode.Child(Mid(strLCaseKey, i, 1))
        Else
            isWord = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    If currNode.isWord Then
        isWord = True
    Else
        isWord = False
    End If
End Function

Public Function getIterator() As clsTrieIterator
    Dim oIterator As clsTrieIterator
    Set oIterator = New clsTrieIterator
    oIterator.Init m_Head
    Set getIterator = oIterator
End Function
```

`clsTrieIterator` is a special class returned by `clsTrie` which allows parsing of a string to be done character by character with `consumeChar` instead of all at once as with `clsTrie.isWord`.  This allows some freedom in parsing the string without backtracking or reading the same character more than once and it allows finding words when you are not sure how long they will be.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private m_currNode As clsTrieNode
Private m_currString As String

Public Property Get getCurrentString() As String
    getCurrentString = m_currString
End Property    

Public Sub Init(oNode As clsTrieNode)
    Set m_currNode = oNode
End Sub

Public Function consumeChar(strChar As String) As Boolean
    Dim strLCaseChar As String
    strLCaseChar = LCase(strChar)
    
    If Not m_currNode.Child(strLCaseChar) Is Nothing Then
        consumeChar = True
        Set m_currNode = m_currNode.Child(strLCaseChar)
        m_currString = m_currString & strChar
    Else
        consumeChar = False
        Set m_currNode = Nothing
    End If
End Function

Public Function isWord() As Boolean
    isWord = m_currNode.isWord
End Function
```

`clsWordFinder` puts everything together in a simple api tailored to your specific problem. It might be worth adding some logic to handle different behavior, like "greedy" matching vs "lazy" matching and overlapping vs nonoverlapping word parsing.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private m_Trie As clsTrie

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_Trie = New clsTrie
End Sub

Public Sub Add(strWord As String)
    m_Trie.Add strWord
End Sub

Public Function getWordsFromString(strString As String) As String
    Dim colIterators As Collection
    Set colIterators = New Collection
    
    Dim colMatches As Collection
    Set colMatches = New Collection
    
    Dim oIterator As clsTrieIterator
    Dim strMatch As String
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim iter
    
    For i = 1 To Len(strString)
        Set oIterator = m_Trie.getIterator
        colIterators.Add oIterator, CStr(ObjPtr(oIterator))
        For Each iter In colIterators
            If Not iter.consumeChar(Mid(strString, i, 1)) Then
                colIterators.Remove CStr(ObjPtr(iter))
            ElseIf iter.isWord() Then
                strMatch = iter.getCurrentString
                Mid(strMatch, 1, 1) = UCase(Mid(strMatch, 1, 1))
                colMatches.Add strMatch
                colIterators.Remove CStr(ObjPtr(iter))
            End If
        Next
    Next
   
    getWordsFromString = JoinCollection(colMatches)
    
End Function

Public Function getWordsCollectionFromString(strString As String) As Collection
    Dim colIterators As Collection
    Set colIterators = New Collection
    
    Dim colMatches As Collection
    Set colMatches = New Collection
    
    Dim oIterator As clsTrieIterator
    Dim strMatch As String
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim iter
    
    For i = 1 To Len(strString)
        Set oIterator = m_Trie.getIterator
        colIterators.Add oIterator, CStr(ObjPtr(oIterator))
        For Each iter In colIterators
            If Not iter.consumeChar(Mid(strString, i, 1)) Then
                colIterators.Remove CStr(ObjPtr(iter))
            ElseIf iter.isWord() Then
                strMatch = iter.getCurrentString
                Mid(strMatch, 1, 1) = UCase(Mid(strMatch, 1, 1))
                colMatches.Add strMatch
                colIterators.Remove CStr(ObjPtr(iter))
            End If
        Next
    Next
    
    Set getWordsCollectionFromString = colMatches
End Function

Private Function JoinCollection(colStrings As Collection, Optional strDelimiter = " ") As String
    Dim strOut As String
    Dim i As Long
    
    If colStrings.Count > 0 Then
        strOut = colStrings.Item(1)
        For i = 2 To colStrings.Count
            strOut = strOut & strDelimiter & colStrings.Item(i)
        Next
        JoinCollection = strOut
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: @vba4all (I know... but I've wanted an excuse to do a trie for a while :) )

Comment: hey, we've got a [VBA chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14929/vba) on CR if you ever interested in doing *cool stuff*

Comment: @Blackhawk you sir, are a legend. Still working on this in my spare time but I really appreciate your input. Guys like you make Stack the awesome resource it is. Thank you brother.